# Change approot path of Windows Azure WebRole

Tags: php, windows, symfony1, azure, document-root

How is it possible to change the default approot path?
E.g. I want to run a PHP Framework whose web root is a sub folder:

```
  symfony
  |_ app
  |_ bin
  |_ src
  |_ web <- Web root
      |_ index.php
```

The web root of the WebRole is there:

```
WebRole <- Web root
 |_ bin
 |_ php
 |_ resources
 |_ WindowsAzureSDKForPHP
 |_ diagnostics.wadcfg
 |_ Global.asax
 |_ Web.config
 |_ index.php
ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
ServiceDefinition.csdef
```

When bringing both togehter I get:

```
WebRole
 |_ bin
 |_ php
 |_ resources
 |_ WindowsAzureSDKForPHP
 |_ diagnostics.wadcfg
 |_ Global.asax
 |_ Web.config
 |_ symfony
      |_ app
      |_ bin
      |_ src
      |_ web <- Desired web root
          |_ index.php      
ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
ServiceDefinition.csdef
```

Is there a way to tell Windows Azure that the web root has changed?
(The defaultDocument-setting in the Web.config is not enough).

**Edit:**

After the suggested changes of astaykov, the structure looks like this:

```
WebRole
 |_ ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
 |_ ServiceDefinition.csdef
 |_ symfony
      |_ app
      |_ bin
      |_ src
      |_ web <- Desired web root
         |_ bin
         |_ php
         |_ resources
         |_ WindowsAzureSDKForPHP
         |_ diagnostics.wadcfg
         |_ Global.asax
         |_ Web.config
         |_ index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding it as another site. For example, add the folling site node to your service definition sites element:

```
 <Site name="symphony" physicalDirectory="../WebRole1/symphony/web">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="www.symphony.com" />
        </Bindings>
  </Site>
```

You need to replace the "Endpoint1" and "www.symphony.com" with your actual endpoint name and host header. I tested it locally and it works (I tested with regular html files, but having php is not much different).

**UPDATE**
Here is deployed sample:

http://sn.cloudapp.net/

http://symphony.staykov.net/

Please note that symphony.staykov.net is just a CNAME to sn.cloudapp.net.

However when deployed, both sites will reside each in its own subfolder of e:\sitesroot. Don't know if it will be an issue for you. How do you include the symphony files in your web? i.e. require_once('../symphony/something.php') ? This would not really work...

I will upload the sample scaffolded solution and provide a link later today or tomorrow.

**UPDATE 2** - sources

You can check the [scaffolded source here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1bce1d5766df232b&resid=1BCE1D5766DF232B!668&parid=1BCE1D5766DF232B!370) and the [actual deploy package here](https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=1bce1d5766df232b&resid=1BCE1D5766DF232B!669&parid=1BCE1D5766DF232B!370) to begin experimenting. Hope that it will give you some ideas on how to solve your issue.

Comment: This does not really work for me, do you have special rewrite rules defined in your Web.config?

Comment: what does not work? If you have some special configuration in your web.config, then just put a copy of the same web.config in ./symphony/web folder. This is becasue now ./symphony/web is a root of a IIS application (separate to the one from your webrole). So if you do have some seeting in web.config - just place the same web.config in the "web" subfolder of symphony and it will work. There might be some issues if you have also ASP.NET pages there, but if it is just PHP - it will work.

Comment: After running "package create" I get a blank page and IIS did not bind the site. I have a copy of the Web.config in WebRole and in the web folder. There are only PHP pages. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: I'll try to assemble test package for you tomorrow.

Comment: Your links and example dos'nt work :( I've the same problem with fuelPHP framework and his "public" subfolder