# Change document root on azure php webrole

Tags: php, laravel, azure, webrole

I want setup Laravel framework on azure webrole and have to change document root, but so far I can't find way how to do this

My deployment project folder:

```
├──webrole <- now this is document root
│  ├──app
│  ├──bin
│  ├──bootstrap
│  ├──config
│  ├──database
│  ├──public <- I want make this as document root
│  ├──resources
│  ├──storage
│  ├──tests
│  ├──vendor
│  ├──.env
│  ├──.env.example
│  ├──.gitattributes
│  ├──.gitignore
│  ├──artisan
│  ├──composer.json
│  ├──composer.lock
│  ├──gulpfile.js
│  ├──package.json
│  ├──phpspec.yml
│  ├──phpunit.xml
│  ├──readme.md
│  ├──server.php
│  ├──Web.cloud.config
│  └──Web.config
├──deploymentSettings.json
├──ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg
├──ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg
├──ServiceDefinition.csdef
```

I found this [Change approot path of Windows Azure WebRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8925139/change-approot-path-of-windows-azure-webrole) but it's quite old question and there isn't approved answer

The only one workaround I've found is using rewrite rules but, I think that is not secure...

Answer (score 0):

As in Azure Cloud Service PHP WebRole directory, where are `web.config` and `web.cloud.config` files which is leveraged to configure PHP site application on IIS.

Web can find the content like the following in these files:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

We can modify the setting `defaultDocument` to change the document root of your laravel application:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="public/index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: That workaround for some php app may work but not for Laravel, Laravel needs rewrite rules to work, anyway one workaround using rewrite rules I've already used, but now I want to change document root

Comment: Which laravel version you are using? As I tested with laravel 4, it worked all fine on my side both on local or Azure Cloud Service.

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: And what have u tested? by that way (without rewrite module) I think routing module won't work...

Comment: I just followed https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-create-web-role/ to create the PHP cloud service, and create a webrole. I copied a laravel 4 application to the webrole directory, and modify the `web.config` and `web.cloud.config`, and publish to azure. browse the cloud service endpoint to check whether it can run

Comment: ah ok, so I think that was default route worked, but if u create route something like this app/do/some/thing that won't work without rewrite rule, but anyway I don't want workarounds, one already have using rewrite rules, I want change document root I know that is possible from IIS but I want configure it in webrole configuration

Comment: for this, you can create another `web,config` in `public` folder to configure the rewrite module for laravel application, just like the original `.htaccess`. you can refer to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/iis7-laravel-5 for the test `web.config` content, or leverage http://htaccesstowebconfig.com/ to convert from your own `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still searching for an answer:

You can change the root directory easily by replacing the nginx configuration file by taking these 2 steps:

1- Add the new configuration file to your project root (wwwroot), we call it `default`.

```
server {
#proxy_cache cache;
#proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
listen 8080;
listen [::]:8080;
root /home/site/wwwroot/public; # changed for Laravel
index  index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name  example.com www.example.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # changed for Laravel
}

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /html/;
}

# Disable .git directory
location ~ /\.git {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
    fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}
```

}

2- Add a startup command to replace the nginx configuration file with your new file.

- Enter your azure resource settings -> configuration.
- General settings tab.
- Startup Command:

  `cp /home/site/wwwroot/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default && service nginx reload`

This should change the document root each time your instance starts.

Resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/flexible-server/tutorial-php-database-app