# Azure php webrole random error 500 on deploy

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-roles

I've experienced strange behavior of azure php webrole deployment, at every second  deploy when I brows page it shows error 500 error, but if I publish again without any changes than it works, I've tried to find something in event viewer but there is nothing

[image], any suggestions?

Some debug info: 
When that error occurred  I checked IIS configuration using remote desktop I've noticed that PHP handler has wrong path specified for example F:\wwwroot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe but on server real path is E:\wwwroot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe I think that drive letter (F:) followed from my system from where I'm publishing
BUT, as I said strange is that one time it work but when I publish it again than error happens...

setup_web.cmd (I've copied it from https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-php-create-web-role/)

```
@ECHO ON
cd "%~dp0"

if "%EMULATED%"=="true" exit /b 0

msiexec /i sqlncli.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES

SET PHP_FULL_PATH=%~dp0php\php-cgi.exe
SET NEW_PATH=%PATH%;%RoleRoot%\base\x86

%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%',maxInstances='12',idleTimeout='60000',activityTimeout='3600',requestTimeout='60000',instanceMaxRequests='10000',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%'].environmentVariables.[name='PATH',value='%NEW_PATH%']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%'].environmentVariables.[name='PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS',value='10000']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='PHP',path='*.php',verb='GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='%PHP_FULL_PATH%',resourceType='Either',requireAccess='Script']" /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:True /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%'].queueLength:50000"
```

UPDATE:
After working around this problem I think problem is following:
I have my project folder on E:\ drive, when I publish first time azure creates E:\ drive and sets php handler path using cmdlets, but when I publish again azure deletes drive E:\ and creates drive F:\ and tries to confugre IIS again bit than it throws following errors:

```
F:\approot\bin>cd "F:\approot\bin\" 

F:\approot\bin>if "false" == "true" exit /b 0 

F:\approot\bin>msiexec /i sqlncli.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES 

F:\approot\bin>SET PHP_FULL_PATH=F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe 

F:\approot\bin>SET NEW_PATH=D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;F:\base\x64;F:\base\x86;;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x64;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x86;;F:\base\x86 

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe',maxInstances='12',idleTimeout='60000',activityTimeout='3600',requestTimeout='60000',instanceMaxRequests='10000',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False']" /commit:apphost 
ERROR ( message:New application object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'application' with combined key attributes 'fullPath, arguments' respectively set to 'F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe, '

. )

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PATH',value='D:\Windows\system32;D:\Windows;D:\Windows\System32\Wbem;D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;;F:\base\x64;F:\base\x86;;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x64;D:\Packages\GuestAgent\GuestAgent\LegacyRuntime\x86;;F:\base\x86']" /commit:apphost 
ERROR ( message:New environmentVariable object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'environmentVariable' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'PATH'

. )

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe'].environmentVariables.[name='PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS',value='10000']" /commit:apphost 
ERROR ( message:New environmentVariable object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'environmentVariable' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS'

. )

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='PHP',path='*.php',verb='GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe',resourceType='Either',requireAccess='Script']" /commit:apphost 
ERROR ( message:New add object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'PHP'

. )

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:True /commit:apphost 
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/urlCompression" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost 
ERROR ( message:New add object missing required attributes. Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'mimeType' set to 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

. )

F:\approot\bin>D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /"[fullPath='F:\approot\bin\php\php-cgi.exe'].queueLength:50000" 
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/fastCgi" for "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST"
```

So I guess it can\'t set configuration of php because it's has been set and therefore throws duplicate errors

So I need something like this: either make so drive letters don't change on publish or change configuration script using following scenario: first remove existing IIS configuration to avoid duplicate errors and than add it again.

Comment: What's your PHP version used in cloud service? And according your another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357846/change-document-root-on-azure-php-webrole, dose this issue occurs in the laracel application? which version of laravel you use? As it's a little difficult to reproduce this issue on my side.

Comment: Yes it's occurs in Laravel application, I'm using php 5.6

Comment: One thing that I've noticed is that, when I publish package and error occurs  php handler in IIS configuration has wrong path specified

Comment: I'm publishing from windows 10 using powershell commands

Comment: I have put some debug info in description, if don't have answer pls up vote question..

Comment: @Phoebus, Could you try to set the Fast-cgi path into the root path? I think you can try to change the" SET PHP_FULL_PATH=%~dp0php\php-cgi.exe" as "SET PHP_FULL_PATH=%RoleRoot\php-cgi.exe
". Any update, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the previous PHP path in the configuration and then set the new one, for example, you have to put this line:

```
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /-"[name='PHP']" /commit:apphost
```

before:

```
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='PHP',path='*.php',verb='GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='%PHP_FULL_PATH%',resourceType='Either',requireAccess='Script']" /commit:apphost
```

Comment: Thank u it helped me to write complete setup script, so I accept your answer and I'll update my question with working setup script.

Answer (score 2):

After maxmayer suggestion, I corrected setup_script

Complete working copy of the script:

```
@ECHO ON
cd "%~dp0"

if "%EMULATED%"=="true" exit /b 0

msiexec /i sqlncli.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLNCLILICENSETERMS=YES

SET PHP_FULL_PATH=%~dp0php\php-cgi.exe
SET NEW_PATH=%PATH%;%RoleRoot%\base\x86

%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /-"[maxInstances='12',idleTimeout='60000',activityTimeout='3600',requestTimeout='60000',instanceMaxRequests='10000',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%',maxInstances='12',idleTimeout='60000',activityTimeout='3600',requestTimeout='60000',instanceMaxRequests='10000',protocol='NamedPipe',flushNamedPipe='False']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%'].environmentVariables.[name='PATH',value='%NEW_PATH%']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /+"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%'].environmentVariables.[name='PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS',value='10000']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /-"[name='PHP']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /+"[name='PHP',path='*.php',verb='GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS',modules='FastCgiModule',scriptProcessor='%PHP_FULL_PATH%',resourceType='Either',requireAccess='Script']" /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:True /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/json; charset=utf-8',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/fastCgi /"[fullPath='%PHP_FULL_PATH%'].queueLength:50000"

REM  clear Laravel cache
cd ..
%~dp0php\php.exe artisan clear-compiled
%~dp0php\php.exe artisan cache:clear
%~dp0php\php.exe artisan config:cache
```